# Using Angular CLI with generated library

Tags: angular-cli

I am building a Angular 10 monorepo app. I used the following commands to generate an empty project and then generate a library and application:

```
ng new myapp --createApplication="false"
cd myapp
ng g application myapp-app
ng g library mylib
```

Both the library and application neatly fall inside the application root's 'project' folder. When I use the Angular CLI to generate any element, they get placed in the application (myapp-app) folder. Running the command `ng generate s test-service`  generates a service inside the `projects/myapp-app/src/app` folder.

How can I use the Angular CLI to generate elements inside the `projects/mylib` folder? Until now I have used the CLI to generate something in the app's folder then I physically move the generated element to the library folder. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular CLI documentation had the [answer](https://angular.io/cli/generate). Use the project flag: `--project=projectName`